# How to loop data for the same id without showing the id repeatedly using foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to display rental amount and days relevant to car id. I'm first displaying car names for  car Make  clicked by user.

When it displays car names,it must display number of rental days and rental amount as well.
But since I store days and amount for a car id in the backend three times, it also loop three times in front end.

To make it clearer:

// in the back end,
I stored the days and amount for a car multiple times instead of one time
**carName** **days** **amount**
carname1      1        50
carname1      7        650
carname1      30       2000

And I'm calling the carName,gallery,rental_days and rental_amount like this:

```
     if(isset($q))
{
mysql_select_db($database);
/*$query_showmake="SELECT carName FROM car_name WHERE carMake_id='$q'";*/
$query_showmake="SELECT rental.rental_days,rental.rental_amount,rental.carName_id,car_name.carName_id,car_name.carName,car_name.carMake_id,gallery,gallery_id,gallery.gallery,gallery.carName_id,car_make.carMake_id  FROM rental,car_name,gallery,car_make WHERE car_name.carName_id=gallery.carName_id AND car_name.carMake_id='$q' AND car_name.carMake_id=car_make.carMake_id AND rental.carName_id=car_name.carName_id ORDER BY rental_days ASC";

$result_showmake=mysql_query($query_showmake)or die(mysql_error());
while($row_showmake=mysql_fetch_array($result_showmake))
{
$carMake_show=$row_showmake['carName'];
$carmake[$row['carName_id']][]=$row_showmake;
/* echo $carMake_show.'<br/>';*/


}
?>
<table border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">
<?php
foreach($carmake as $make=>$name)
{

foreach($name as $n)
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='carname'>".$n{'carName'}.'</td><td rowspan="2" valign="top" class="cardetail">Car Details</td></tr>';
/*echo $n{'carMake_id'}.'<br/>';
echo $n{'gallery'}.'<br/>';*/
echo"<tr><td class='img'><img src='management/uploads/{$n['carMake_id']}/{$n['gallery']}' width='400' height='200'>";
echo "</td></tr>";
echo"<tr><td colspan='2' class='days'>Days : ";
$days[]=$n['rental_days'];
foreach($days as $day)
{
echo $day."&nbsp;";
}
echo "</td></tr>";

echo"<tr><td colspan='2' class='days'>Amount : ";
$amount[]=$n['rental_amount'];
foreach($amount as $amt)
{
echo "RM ".$amt."&nbsp;";
}
echo "</td></tr>";
echo"<tr><td height='50' colspan='2'></td></tr>";

}
}?>
</table>
<?php
}
```

And it displays the result like this:

carName 1
image 1
days 1
amount 50

carName 1
image 1
days 7
amount 650

carName 1
image 1
days 30
amount 2000

AND I want to display like:

carname 1
days:1    7      30
amt: 50  650   2000

Comment: What part returns the ID? You have commented out the **$n{'carMake_id'}** bit

Comment: @dwhite.me I showed as though it displays id just to make it easier to understand but actual code doesn't display....It's teh id of car so should be carName_id ,if I actually put it in code.

Comment: Ok, show us what you have **actually** done. What you are asking is somewhat vague.

Comment: Do you really need `foreach($name as $n)` ? Because I think you can get your query result from `$name` itself. For me, the easiest way would be not to directly `echo` your HTML tags instead, save it in a variable until the next `$n{'carName'} != 1` or different from previous record(s), then echo the result and go to the next record.

Answer (score 0):

In your main fetch loop stack the values you want to display in an indexed array like this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_showmake)) {
    $carmake[$row['carName_id']]['amounts'][] = $row['rental_amount'];
    $carmake[$row['carName_id']]['days'][] = $row['rental_days'];
    $carmake[$row['carName_id']]['images'][] = $row['gallery'];
}
```

Then use [**`implode`**](http://php.net/implode) to render the stacked values as a space separated string

```
foreach($carmake as $id => $make) {
    print "carName $id\n"
         . "images " . implode(' ', $make['images']) . "\n"
         . "days " . implode(' ', $make['days']) . "\n"
         . "amounts " . implode(' ', $make['amounts']) . "\n";
}
```

Btw, you shouldn't use mysql_* functions as they're deprecated. Consider moving to [**`mysqli`**](http://php.net/mysqli) or [**`PDO`**](http://php.net/pdo).

Comment: ,thanks for your help , I tried but it doesn't work for me...All I need is to loop through the day and amount of rental according to the care name.. I believe through foreach loop can achieve this but don't know how??